# How to join the parent table when using STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have these models:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :units
end

class Unit < Product
  belongs_to :product
end
```

The models above uses one table only which is called `'products'` table.

```rb
create_table :products do |t|
  t.string  :code
  t.integer :product_id
  t.string  :type
  t.string  :status
  ...
end
```

What I want is to get all the `units` where `products.status` is `active`.

I tried `Unit.joins(:product).where(products: { status: 'active' })` but no luck

Here's the current data I have

```
| id |  type   | product_id | status  |
|----|:-------:|-----------:|---------|
| 1  | Product |       null | deleted |
| 2  | Product |       null | active  |
| 3  |  Unit   |          1 | active  |
| 4  |  Unit   |          1 | active  |
| 5  |  Unit   |          2 | active  |
```

All I want to get is

```
| id |  type   | product_id | status  |
|----|:-------:|-----------:|---------|
| 5  |  Unit   |          2 | active  |
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

Your use case doesn't make sense to use STI. Use a `has_many/belongs_to` like so:

```
# notice we inherit from ApplicationRecord now instead
class Unit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Then you can run your query like:

```
Product.joins(:units).where(units: {status: 'active'})
```

---

### Explanation:

It doesn't make sense to have a `belongs_to` -> `has_many` relationship between two tables inheriting from the same parent. Two tables with STI is another way of saying "these two models are specific types of a more general model."

For example:

```
# the parent class your other children classes will inherit from
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  # and let's say in the database vehicle has a column of:
  # color: :string

  def honk
    puts 'beep!'
  end
end

# Car inherits methods and attributes of Vehicle, and can also define 
# its own methods particular to cars
class Car < Vehicle
  def sunroof?
    # logic here
  end
end

# Motorcycle inherits methods and attributes of Vehicle, and can also define
# its own methods particular to motorcycles
class Motorcycle < Vehicle
  def sidecar?
    # logic here
  end
end
```

As you can see, the purpose of STI is to share common methods and attributes (in the example above, the `honk` method and the `:color` attribute) so that you don't waste time and cause potential application issues by defining them twice.

In contrast, a `belongs_to`/`has_many` association is for defining a relationship between two totally separate but related models. For example:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :library

  ...
end

class Library < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books

  ...
end
```

And this would allow us to do useful things in our application such as checking which books a given library can lend:

```
library = Library.first
library.books
=> # a bunch of book objects returned from the db
```